# FEniCS: evaluate gradient of function at point

Tags: python, gradient, post-processing, fenics

Let `u` be the solution to a given problem solved using FEniCS, on a function space `V`

```
from fenics import *
...
u = Function(V)
solve(a==L, u, bcs)
```

and `x` be a `Point` object. How do I evaluate the gradient of ﻿u﻿ at ﻿x﻿ ?

---

I tried

```
g = grad(u)
g(x)
```

which raises an error about dimensions :

```
UFLException: Expecting dim to match the geometric dimension, got dim=1 and gdim=2.
```

Projecting the gradient on the function space doesn't give encouraging results either:

```
h = project(grad(u), V)
```

also raises an error

```
UFLException: Shape mismatch.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have dimensions problems, while projecting a function in a scalar function space. you might need to do something like this:

```
 V_vec = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "CG", 1)
 h = project(grad(u),V_vec)
```

Regards, Leonardo